# Compare with null Date in range

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Document
public class Product extends Item {
    private Date onlineDate;

    private Date offlineDate;
}
```

Data

```
Product {
    onlineDate : some date
    offlineDate : null
}
```

below query return 0 hits

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("onlineDate").lte(date).and("offlineDate").gte(date))
```

but below query returns results

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("onlineDate").lte(date))
```

is this something that I am not allowed to compare with null date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to include conditions to accept the `null` in the results. Right now you are asking *"is greater than"* a supplied date, and `null` is not "greater than", therefore it is exluded.

This means adding an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition to test for both possible conditions on that field:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("onlinedate").lte(date).orOperator(
    Criteria.where("offlinedate").gte(date),
    Criteria.where("offlinedate").is(null)
);

Query query = new Query().addCriteria(criteria);

System.out.println(query.getQueryObject());
```

Which would give you:

```
{ 
    "onlinedate" : { "$lte" : date } , 
    "$or" : [ 
        { "offlinedate" : { "$gte" : date } } , 
        { "offlinedate" :  null }
    ]
}
```

That is the correct translation of altering your query to allow the `null` value, but it does make me think that your basic thinking on the query is incorrect since this would return results that basically say *"still online"*. That may be what you want, but then again you might have been intending to ask something different.

If in fact you were looking for "all" document that did **not** have the supplied `date` value "betweeen" the two values in the document, then you would instead "invert" the range expressions to match documents "between" and then "invert" the result with [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) instead:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().norOperator(
   Criteria.where("onlinedate").gte(date)
   .and("offlinedate").lte(date)
);

Query query = new Query().addCriteria(criteria);

System.out.println(query.getQueryObject());
```

Which results in a query like this:

```
{
    "$nor" : [ 
        { 
            "onlinedate" : { "$gte" : date }, 
            "offlinedate" : { "$lte" : date }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is returning results both "before" and "after" the range between the two date properties, or where the `"offline"` date was `null` and the range is not "closed".

It depends on which set of results you actually want, being either that you include the `null` values to find the data that is "still open" or you just "exclude the range" to find the data that falls outside of the range instead.